# Expressing double summation in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to express a function $u(r,\theta)$ in terms of some modes $m,n$, as follows

$$u(r,\theta)=\sum_m\sum_n A_{mn}\phi_{mn}(r)e^{im\theta}$$

where $\phi_{mn}$ are the mode functions and $A_{mn}$ are the coefficients. Firstly, is there any way to express $u(r,\theta)$ in matrix form?

Finally, I only know matrix $C = uu^*$, and I would like to calculate the functions $\phi_{mn}$ and coefficients $AA^*$ by using POD or EVM, or any other approaches. The idea is to express $u$ into least possible modes. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

$$u (r, \theta) = \langle \mathrm D (\theta) \, \mathrm A , \Phi (r) \rangle$$

where

$$\mathrm D (\theta) = \mbox{diag} ( e^{i \theta}, e^{i 2\theta}, \dots, e^{i m \theta})$$

Comment: Thanks for it. Is there any way to express $A$ and $\phi$ in terms of $C$ and $D(\theta)$using POD or SVD. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What is $\rm C$? What is POD?

Comment: C is a matrix which is $uu^*$ and POD is proper orthogonal decomposition or singular value decomposition. Not necessarily to use POD or SVD but I would like to estimate $A,\phi$ in terms of C. How can I express $[uu^*]$?